# Creating multi level repositories in SVN

Tags: svn, repository

We are planning to create a multi level repository with the following structure

```
RepositoryRoot
    |
    --- Framework
    |      |
    |      --- ArchitectureProj1
    |      |
    |      --- ArchitectureProj2
    |
    --- Application
           |
           --- Project1
           |
           --- Project2
```

But how do I create such a repository using the svnadmin command. The documentation of the command shows the creation of the repository and then immediately go on to create projects. But nothing much on creating a custom folder structure (outside of the project)

So I created the repository, Now I know how to create the project as well. But I need to create the structure as depicted above before I start creating the projects. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean just normal folders? Or do you mean repositories inside repositories? ie. will Project1 and Project2 be complete Subversion repositories stored separate?

Comment: You can create any hierarchy you like inside a repository - it's not mandatory to use tags/trunk/branches. You have to do it with the client, though `svn mkdir` not svnadmin

Comment: So then just create the folders and add them to the repository, there's nothing magical about the folders created by the normal wizards, like trunk, branches, tags, etc. They're just folders with a special meaning only through convention (ie. they're special because people treat them special)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the structure inside the repository by using the

```
svn mkdir URL....
```

Or simpler create the structure on Harddrive and later import that structure into the repository via

```
svn import ....
```

Answer (score 1):

As almost everything else in Subversion, the structure you describe can (only) be accomplished by creating regular directories inside your repository, using your favourite **client** (not *svnadmin*). My advise is that you create the folder structure somewhere on your hard disk and then run a `svn import` command. After that, coders will just need to checkout the repository path for their project.